# Log exception only at nth time it occurs

Tags: java, exception

I have a situation that the same exception is thrown too often and floods the log/console. 
the code logic is like:

```
public void run(){
    ....
    try {
    } catch (Throwable trace) {
        LOG.error("catch throwable" , trace);   
    }  
}
```

Is there a way that I can change the 'catch' block, so that it only logs the nth time?

```
catch (Throwable trace) {
    if ( the 100th time)
        LOG.error("catch throwable" , trace);   
    else 
        LOG.error("catch throwable"); 
}
```

Comment: Should that be for the same class?

Comment: Side Note: You might want to look into why the exception being thrown so often.

Comment: Exceptions are very expensive. You should add more checking code to avoid them.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:**

Exceptions are very expensive.

You should not use them for control flow but instead should add checks (using if statements such as: `if(AAA==null)` ) to avoid the exceptions in the first place.

**Code:**

The below would take care of it. You have a counter incrementing every time there is an exception. You take this modulo N, and when the result is zero, you log the error.

```
private int exceptionCounter = 1;
private static int N = 100;

public void run(){
    ....
    try {
    } catch (Throwable trace) {
        if(exceptionCounter++ % N == 0)
            LOG.error("catch throwable:" + String.valueOf(exceptionCounter ) + " Exceptions thrown." , trace);   
    }  
}
```

### Update

If your after a shared multi-threaded ExceptionCounter you need to use an atomic variable.

```
private static AtomicInteger exceptionCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    private static int N = 100;

    public void run(){
        ....
        try {
        } catch (Throwable trace) {
            if(exceptionCounter.incrementAndGet() % N == 0)
                LOG.error("catch throwable:" + String.valueOf(exceptionCounter ) + " Exceptions thrown." , trace);   
        }  
    }
```

Comment: I like this better: `if ((exceptionCounter = (exceptionCounter + 1) % N) == 0)`. Although your way still works even if `exceptionCounter` overflows, I dislike the thought of the overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

If you think you might need this feature lots, then most logging frameworks offer a way to intercept log attempts.  By extending the framework, you can decide whether or not to log something.  You might even get all fancy and delay all logging by a short period, and if in that period, the same log is repeated, just merge it with the previous, along with a counter.

The first example of this that I found while google was this [email throttler for log4j](https://github.com/reaktor/log4j-email-throttle) which uses [TriggeringEventEvaluator](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/TriggeringEventEvaluator.html).  Are you using log4j?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You could limit the number of times the exception is thrown by declaring a global variable that is incremented in the "catch" block, and a conditional that would terminate the program if the variable's value is sufficiently large.

Comment: thanks. is there way to limit the change to the 'catch' block? or within the 'run()' method?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by "limit the change."  You could make the variable private in the class in question to restrict the scope of change to the class, or pass the variable between run() and all the methods that call it as an explicit parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a static volatile variable (which are accessible across threads) counting the number of times the catch block has been entered and then use the `%` operator to determine if it is a multiple of e.g. 10.

I would, however, suggest that you look into logging to files instead.  A good log file is invaluable when needing to solve a problem in a program after it has finished.